# Product attribute drop down value show according to it's parent drop down selection

Tags: magento2.3

I want to product attribute(attribute2) having input type select depend on other attribute's (attribute1)value on admin side.

For example, Customer module state dropdown selection based on country.

In my case, I have two dropdown "destination", and "location". location dropdown value select based on destination value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the same behavior as the State/Provide (or `region_id`) field in the Customer Address Form, then I would recommend creating a new JavaScript component using that field's component as a reference. However, this means you won't be able to use it as a typical attribute because you'll have to manually add the field as a JS component. So the alternative is I suppose inject a JavaScript file that will listen for the changes of the first dropdown and update the available options of the 2nd.

**JS Component Approach**

To get started, check out [Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_form.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_form.xml#L202). As of Magento 2.3.1 you'll be looking at line 202 for `<field name="region_id...`. This is where that State/Province field is created. From there you can see the component is `Magento_Customer/js/form/element/region`.

So to find this you'll look at [Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/region.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/region.js). From here you can see it inherits another `region` component, so you'll probably need to dig into it as well.

Once you get your bearings with the existing components, you'll need to start creating your own. You can create the file `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml` in your module and add the component in there.

**Attribute Approach**

Create the file `view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit_edit.xml` in your module, and inject your JS like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Modulename::js/dynamic_dropdown.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then in your module create your JS file (for example `view/adminhtml/web/js/dynamic_dropdown.js`). As a starting point it can be something like the following.

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // custom js
    });

});
```

Then add your custom JS logic here.